# Short novel about artificial infertile girls coming from Venus to marry men and eliminate human race

Tags: story-identification, novel

Short novel about artificial infertile girls coming from Venus to marry men and eliminate the human race through infertility.

There was a "happy" ending (quite questionable) - men just started to get second wives.